# Kafka Topic creation - Timed out waiting for a node assignment

Tags: google-cloud-platform, apache-kafka

I have deployed Single node Kafka on GCP using - https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/details/click-to-deploy-images/kafka

**server.properties file looks like below:**

**Note** : listeners has appeared twice. Once (commented) under "Socket Server Settings" and 2nd time (uncommented)  under "Group Coordinator Settings"

```
############################# Socket Server Settings #############################
            
# The address the socket server listens on. If not configured, the host name will be equal to the value of
# java.net.InetAddress.getCanonicalHostName(), with PLAINTEXT listener name, and port 9092.
#   FORMAT:
#     listeners = listener_name://host_name:port
#   EXAMPLE:
#     listeners = PLAINTEXT://your.host.name:9092
#listeners=PLAINTEXT://:9092

# Listener name, hostname and port the broker will advertise to clients.
# If not set, it uses the value for "listeners".
#advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://your.host.name:9092
        
############################# Zookeeper #############################

# Zookeeper connection string (see zookeeper docs for details).
# This is a comma separated host:port pairs, each corresponding to a zk
# server. e.g. "127.0.0.1:3000,127.0.0.1:3001,127.0.0.1:3002".
# You can also append an optional chroot string to the urls to specify the
# root directory for all kafka znodes.
zookeeper.connect=localhost:2181
    
############################# Group Coordinator Settings #############################

# The following configuration specifies the time, in milliseconds, that the GroupCoordinator will delay the initial consumer rebalance.
# The rebalance will be further delayed by the value of group.initial.rebalance.delay.ms as new members join the group, up to a maximum of max.poll.interval.ms.
# The default value for this is 3 seconds.
# We override this to 0 here as it makes for a better out-of-the-box experience for development and testing.
# However, in production environments the default value of 3 seconds is more suitable as this will help to avoid unnecessary, and potentially expensive, rebalances during application startup.
group.initial.rebalance.delay.ms=0
######## C2D Custom Configuration ########
security.inter.broker.protocol=SASL_PLAINTEXT
sasl.mechanism.inter.broker.protocol=PLAIN
sasl.enabled.mechanisms=PLAIN
auto.create.topics.enable=true
authorizer.class.name=kafka.security.authorizer.AclAuthorizer
allow.everyone.if.no.acl.found=true
listeners=SASL_PLAINTEXT://0.0.0.0:9092
advertised.listeners=SASL_PLAINTEXT://:9092
```

Question: trying to create kafka topic, but running into **Error while executing topic command : Timed out waiting for a node assignment. Call: createTopics**

Hence uncommented listeners and changed under section "Socket Server Settings" from #listeners=PLAINTEXT://:9092 to listeners=PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092 , But running into same issue.

Hence later commented out above as earlier and changed both listeners and advertised.listeners under "Group Coordinator Settings" as below.

listeners=SASL_PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092

advertised.listeners=SASL_PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092

**Executed below commands to create topic:**
All of these commands are running into same issue.

```
kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --create --topic TestKafkaTopic --partitions 1 --replication-factor 1

kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper localhost:9092 --create --topic TestKafkaTopic --partitions 1 --replication-factor 1

kafka-topics.sh --create --bootstrap-server localhost:2181 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1 --topic TestKafkaTopic

kafka-topics.sh --create --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1 --topic TestKafkaTopic

kafka-topics.sh --create --bootstrap-server 127.0.0.1:9092 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1 --topic TestKafkaTopic
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use SASL listeners you need to provide JAAS config files to each of the CLI commands for authentication.

If that's not what you want, you should use PLAINTEXT listeners/advertised.listeners, but only one uncommented line of each

It's also not clear where you're running those commands, but the Google Cloud Console or your local machine isn't the server running Kafka - you need to use its external IP/hostname, not localhost, and --zookeeper flag has been removed in recent Kafka versions, so only use bootstrap servers

There are better options if you truly want "click to deploy" that don't require messing with config files

Comment: I'm running the command from Google cloud web console. I dont' have any preference of listeners, hence commented out SASL listeners and SASL advertised listeners. Uncommented both listeners (listeners=PLAINTEXT://<ext_ip_add>:9092) and advertised listeners(advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://<ext_ip_add>:9092) under Socket Server Settings section above, added external IP of the compute engine. Still running into same error message. Command used $ kafka-topics.sh --create --bootstrap-server <external_ip_add_value>:9092 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1 --topic TestKafkaTopic

Comment: What if you try [SSH to the instance](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/connect/standard-ssh#gcloud), then try using localhost?

Comment: running the command by SSH to the instance (direct ssh to VM as well as ssh via cloud web console). Running into same error message when creating the topic.

Comment: If you cannot create the topics from the broker itself, sounds like Kafka broker process isn't running

Comment: the log file /opt/kafka/logs/server.log  has following message --> INFO [SocketServer listenerType=ZK_BROKER, nodeId=0] Failed authentication with /<EXT_IP_ADD_VAL> (channelId=<INT_IP_ADD_VAL>:9092-<EXT_IP_ADD_VAL>.74:36642-1341) (Unexpected Kafka request of type METADATA during SASL handshake.) (org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector).  So to try out another way using SASL listeners, commented out earlier listeners used, enabled SASL listeners as listeners=SASL_PLAINTEXT://<EXT_IP_ADD_VAL>:9092 and advertised.listeners=SASL_PLAINTEXT://<EXT_IP_ADD_VAL>:9092 , executed topic creation scripts

Comment: $ kafka-topics.sh --create --bootstrap-server <EXT_IP_ADD_VAL>:9092 --topic TestKafkaTopic --command-config /opt/kafka/config/kafka_server_jaas.conf 

kafka_server_jaas.conf  has username and password. But running into same error 'Timed out waiting for a node assignment'. Any pointers to further debug would be helpful.

Comment: can you also suggest other better ways you mentioned for "click to deploy" that don't require messing with config files. Basically we plan to deploy a single node (or 1-3 nodes) cluster with limited pricing for exploratory PoC and want to host only on GCP.

Comment: Without having access to your cluster, I don't have any suggestions to debug.  The command config needs to use a client JAAS file, which has different content than the server's... You could try Aiven or Confluent Cloud, for example, and link with your GCP account, which have a better support model