# Kafka - Disconnecting from node due to socket connection setup timeout

Tags: google-cloud-platform, apache-kafka

I have single node Kafka setup on GCP. Launched a VM, installed Java and Kafka. Running the commands on gcloud shell by ssh to host.

Set the listeners as below in server.properties file:

```
listeners=PLAINTEXT://:9092    #Also tried with localhost
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://<ext_ip_add_val>:9092
```

Due to the disconnect (server.log posted at the end), When I try to list existing topics using /bin/kafka-topics.sh --list --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 , running into error "Timed out waiting for a node assignment"

**jps result:**

```
9852 QuorumPeerMain
10844 Jps
```

I also removed both Zookeeper and Kafka directory, started zookeeper and broker. Also tried to release the port using below command , but running into same issue.

```
sudo fuser -k 9092/tcp
```

**Update**: Adding server.properties

```
############################# Server Basics #############################

# The id of the broker. This must be set to a unique integer for each broker.
broker.id=0

############################# Socket Server Settings #############################

# The address the socket server listens on. If not configured, the host name will be equal to the value of
# java.net.InetAddress.getCanonicalHostName(), with PLAINTEXT listener name, and port 9092.
#   FORMAT:
#     listeners = listener_name://host_name:port
#   EXAMPLE:
#     listeners = PLAINTEXT://your.host.name:9092
listeners=PLAINTEXT://:9092

# Listener name, hostname and port the broker will advertise to clients.
# If not set, it uses the value for "listeners".
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://<EXT_IP_ADD_VAL>:9092

# Maps listener names to security protocols, the default is for them to be the same. See the config documentation for more details
#listener.security.protocol.map=PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,SSL:SSL,SASL_PLAINTEXT:SASL_PLAINTEXT,SASL_SSL:SASL_SSL

# The number of threads that the server uses for receiving requests from the network and sending responses to the network
num.network.threads=3

# The number of threads that the server uses for processing requests, which may include disk I/O
num.io.threads=8

# The send buffer (SO_SNDBUF) used by the socket server
socket.send.buffer.bytes=102400

# The receive buffer (SO_RCVBUF) used by the socket server
socket.receive.buffer.bytes=102400

# The maximum size of a request that the socket server will accept (protection against OOM)
socket.request.max.bytes=104857600


############################# Log Basics #############################

# A comma separated list of directories under which to store log files
log.dirs=/tmp/kafka-logs

# The default number of log partitions per topic. More partitions allow greater
# parallelism for consumption, but this will also result in more files across
# the brokers.
num.partitions=1

# The number of threads per data directory to be used for log recovery at startup and flushing at shutdown.
# This value is recommended to be increased for installations with data dirs located in RAID array.
num.recovery.threads.per.data.dir=1

############################# Internal Topic Settings  #############################
# The replication factor for the group metadata internal topics "__consumer_offsets" and "__transaction_state"
# For anything other than development testing, a value greater than 1 is recommended to ensure availability such as 3.
offsets.topic.replication.factor=1
transaction.state.log.replication.factor=1
transaction.state.log.min.isr=1

############################# Log Flush Policy #############################

# Messages are immediately written to the filesystem but by default we only fsync() to sync
# the OS cache lazily. The following configurations control the flush of data to disk.
# There are a few important trade-offs here:
#    1. Durability: Unflushed data may be lost if you are not using replication.
#    2. Latency: Very large flush intervals may lead to latency spikes when the flush does occur as there will be a lot of data to flush.
#    3. Throughput: The flush is generally the most expensive operation, and a small flush interval may lead to excessive seeks.
# The settings below allow one to configure the flush policy to flush data after a period of time or
# every N messages (or both). This can be done globally and overridden on a per-topic basis.

# The number of messages to accept before forcing a flush of data to disk
#log.flush.interval.messages=10000

# The maximum amount of time a message can sit in a log before we force a flush
#log.flush.interval.ms=1000

############################# Log Retention Policy #############################

# The following configurations control the disposal of log segments. The policy can
# be set to delete segments after a period of time, or after a given size has accumulated.
# A segment will be deleted whenever *either* of these criteria are met. Deletion always happens
# from the end of the log.

# The minimum age of a log file to be eligible for deletion due to age
log.retention.hours=168

# A size-based retention policy for logs. Segments are pruned from the log unless the remaining
# segments drop below log.retention.bytes. Functions independently of log.retention.hours.
#log.retention.bytes=1073741824

# The maximum size of a log segment file. When this size is reached a new log segment will be created.
#log.segment.bytes=1073741824

# The interval at which log segments are checked to see if they can be deleted according
# to the retention policies
log.retention.check.interval.ms=300000

############################# Zookeeper #############################

# Zookeeper connection string (see zookeeper docs for details).
# This is a comma separated host:port pairs, each corresponding to a zk
# server. e.g. "127.0.0.1:3000,127.0.0.1:3001,127.0.0.1:3002".
# You can also append an optional chroot string to the urls to specify the
# root directory for all kafka znodes.
zookeeper.connect=0.0.0.0:2181

# Timeout in ms for connecting to zookeeper
zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms=18000


############################# Group Coordinator Settings #############################

# The following configuration specifies the time, in milliseconds, that the GroupCoordinator will delay the initial consumer rebalance.
# The rebalance will be further delayed by the value of group.initial.rebalance.delay.ms as new members join the group, up to a maximum of max.poll.interval.ms.
# The default value for this is 3 seconds.
# We override this to 0 here as it makes for a better out-of-the-box experience for development and testing.
# However, in production environments the default value of 3 seconds is more suitable as this will help to avoid unnecessary, and potentially expensive, rebalances during application startup.
group.initial.rebalance.delay.ms=0
```

**zookeeper.properties :**

```
# the directory where the snapshot is stored.
dataDir=/tmp/zookeeper
# the port at which the clients will connect
clientPort=2181
# disable the per-ip limit on the number of connections since this is a non-production config
maxClientCnxns=0
# Disable the adminserver by default to avoid port conflicts.
# Set the port to something non-conflicting if choosing to enable this
4lw.commands.whitelist=stat, ruok, conf, isro
admin.enableServer=false
# admin.serverPort=8080
```

**server.log:**

```
    [2023-07-29 09:26:07,022] INFO Client environment:java.io.tmpdir=/tmp (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
    [2023-07-29 09:26:07,022] INFO Client environment:java.compiler=<NA> (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
    [2023-07-29 09:26:07,022] INFO Client environment:os.name=Linux (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
    [2023-07-29 09:26:07,022] INFO Client environment:os.arch=amd64 (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
    [2023-07-29 09:26:07,023] INFO Client environment:os.version=5.15.0-1038-gcp (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
    [2023-07-29 09:26:07,023] INFO Client environment:user.name=root (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
    [2023-07-29 09:26:07,023] INFO Client environment:user.home=/root (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
    [2023-07-29 09:26:07,023] INFO Client environment:user.dir=/home/user (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
    [2023-07-29 09:26:07,023] INFO Client environment:os.memory.free=972MB (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
    [2023-07-29 09:26:07,023] INFO Client environment:os.memory.max=1024MB (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
    [2023-07-29 09:26:07,023] INFO Client environment:os.memory.total=1024MB (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
    [2023-07-29 09:26:07,025] INFO Initiating client connection, connectString=0.0.0.0:2181 sessionTimeout=18000 watcher=kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient$ZooKeeperClientWatcher$@4d518b32 (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
    [2023-07-29 09:26:07,042] INFO jute.maxbuffer value is 4194304 Bytes (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocket)
    [2023-07-29 09:26:07,047] INFO zookeeper.request.timeout value is 0. feature enabled=false (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
    [2023-07-29 09:26:07,052] INFO [ZooKeeperClient Kafka server] Waiting until connected. (kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient)
    [2023-07-29 09:26:07,055] INFO Opening socket connection to server /0.0.0.0:2181. (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
    [2023-07-29 09:26:07,061] INFO Socket connection established, initiating session, client: /10.142.0.8:59672, server: /0.0.0.0:2181 (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
    [2023-07-29 09:26:07,098] INFO Session establishment complete on server /0.0.0.0:2181, session id = 0x10001e90bc40000, negotiated timeout = 18000 (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
    [2023-07-29 09:26:07,105] INFO [ZooKeeperClient Kafka server] Connected. (kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient)
    [2023-07-29 09:26:07,439] INFO Cluster ID = UzcC_uEISGKlanfxqs_BjQ (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
    [2023-07-29 09:26:07,444] WARN No meta.properties file under dir /tmp/kafka-logs/meta.properties (kafka.server.BrokerMetadataCheckpoint)
    [2023-07-29 09:26:07,529] INFO KafkaConfig values: 
   
 <removed from this post due to char limit>
  
    [2023-07-29 09:26:07,582] INFO [ThrottledChannelReaper-Fetch]: Starting (kafka.server.ClientQuotaManager$ThrottledChannelReaper)
    [2023-07-29 09:26:07,588] INFO [ThrottledChannelReaper-Produce]: Starting (kafka.server.ClientQuotaManager$ThrottledChannelReaper)
    [2023-07-29 09:26:07,590] INFO [ThrottledChannelReaper-Request]: Starting (kafka.server.ClientQuotaManager$ThrottledChannelReaper)
    [2023-07-29 09:26:07,593] INFO [ThrottledChannelReaper-ControllerMutation]: Starting (kafka.server.ClientQuotaManager$ThrottledChannelReaper)
    [2023-07-29 09:26:07,613] INFO Log directory /tmp/kafka-logs not found, creating it. (kafka.log.LogManager)
    [2023-07-29 09:26:07,636] INFO Loading logs from log dirs ArrayBuffer(/tmp/kafka-logs) (kafka.log.LogManager)
    [2023-07-29 09:26:07,640] INFO No logs found to be loaded in /tmp/kafka-logs (kafka.log.LogManager)
    [2023-07-29 09:26:07,653] INFO Loaded 0 logs in 17ms (kafka.log.LogManager)
    [2023-07-29 09:26:07,656] INFO Starting log cleanup with a period of 300000 ms. (kafka.log.LogManager)
    [2023-07-29 09:26:07,658] INFO Starting log flusher with a default period of 9223372036854775807 ms. (kafka.log.LogManager)
    [2023-07-29 09:26:07,721] INFO [kafka-log-cleaner-thread-0]: Starting (kafka.log.LogCleaner$CleanerThread)
    [2023-07-29 09:26:07,739] INFO [feature-zk-node-event-process-thread]: Starting (kafka.server.FinalizedFeatureChangeListener$ChangeNotificationProcessorThread)
    [2023-07-29 09:26:07,752] INFO Feature ZK node at path: /feature does not exist (kafka.server.FinalizedFeatureChangeListener)
    [2023-07-29 09:26:07,784] INFO [zk-broker-0-to-controller-forwarding-channel-manager]: Starting (kafka.server.BrokerToControllerRequestThread)
    [2023-07-29 09:26:08,156] INFO Updated connection-accept-rate max connection creation rate to 2147483647 (kafka.network.ConnectionQuotas)
    [2023-07-29 09:26:08,180] INFO [SocketServer listenerType=ZK_BROKER, nodeId=0] Created data-plane acceptor and processors for endpoint : ListenerName(PLAINTEXT) (kafka.network.SocketServer)
    [2023-07-29 09:26:08,201] INFO [zk-broker-0-to-controller-alter-partition-channel-manager]: Starting (kafka.server.BrokerToControllerRequestThread)
    [2023-07-29 09:26:08,223] INFO [ExpirationReaper-0-Produce]: Starting (kafka.server.DelayedOperationPurgatory$ExpiredOperationReaper)
    [2023-07-29 09:26:08,225] INFO [ExpirationReaper-0-Fetch]: Starting (kafka.server.DelayedOperationPurgatory$ExpiredOperationReaper)
    [2023-07-29 09:26:08,230] INFO [ExpirationReaper-0-DeleteRecords]: Starting (kafka.server.DelayedOperationPurgatory$ExpiredOperationReaper)
    [2023-07-29 09:26:08,231] INFO [ExpirationReaper-0-ElectLeader]: Starting (kafka.server.DelayedOperationPurgatory$ExpiredOperationReaper)
    [2023-07-29 09:26:08,257] INFO [LogDirFailureHandler]: Starting (kafka.server.ReplicaManager$LogDirFailureHandler)
    [2023-07-29 09:26:08,278] INFO Creating /brokers/ids/0 (is it secure? false) (kafka.zk.KafkaZkClient)
    [2023-07-29 09:26:08,305] INFO Stat of the created znode at /brokers/ids/0 is: 25,25,1690622768294,1690622768294,1,0,0,72059694474330112,208,0,25
     (kafka.zk.KafkaZkClient)
    [2023-07-29 09:26:08,307] INFO Registered broker 0 at path /brokers/ids/0 with addresses: PLAINTEXT://<ext_ip_add_val>:9092, czxid (broker epoch): 25 (kafka.zk.KafkaZkClient)
    [2023-07-29 09:26:08,401] INFO [ExpirationReaper-0-topic]: Starting (kafka.server.DelayedOperationPurgatory$ExpiredOperationReaper)
    [2023-07-29 09:26:08,410] INFO [ExpirationReaper-0-Heartbeat]: Starting (kafka.server.DelayedOperationPurgatory$ExpiredOperationReaper)
    [2023-07-29 09:26:08,413] INFO [ExpirationReaper-0-Rebalance]: Starting (kafka.server.DelayedOperationPurgatory$ExpiredOperationReaper)
    [2023-07-29 09:26:08,420] INFO Successfully created /controller_epoch with initial epoch 0 (kafka.zk.KafkaZkClient)
    [2023-07-29 09:26:08,441] INFO [GroupCoordinator 0]: Starting up. (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator)
    [2023-07-29 09:26:08,451] INFO Feature ZK node created at path: /feature (kafka.server.FinalizedFeatureChangeListener)
    [2023-07-29 09:26:08,453] INFO [GroupCoordinator 0]: Startup complete. (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator)
    [2023-07-29 09:26:08,475] INFO [TransactionCoordinator id=0] Starting up. (kafka.coordinator.transaction.TransactionCoordinator)
    [2023-07-29 09:26:08,482] INFO [TransactionCoordinator id=0] Startup complete. (kafka.coordinator.transaction.TransactionCoordinator)
    [2023-07-29 09:26:08,486] INFO [MetadataCache brokerId=0] Updated cache from existing <empty> to latest FinalizedFeaturesAndEpoch(features=Map(), epoch=0). (kafka.server.metadata.ZkMetadataCache)
    [2023-07-29 09:26:08,492] INFO [TxnMarkerSenderThread-0]: Starting (kafka.coordinator.transaction.TransactionMarkerChannelManager)
    [2023-07-29 09:26:08,526] INFO [ExpirationReaper-0-AlterAcls]: Starting (kafka.server.DelayedOperationPurgatory$ExpiredOperationReaper)
    [2023-07-29 09:26:08,569] INFO [/config/changes-event-process-thread]: Starting (kafka.common.ZkNodeChangeNotificationListener$ChangeEventProcessThread)
    [2023-07-29 09:26:08,599] INFO [SocketServer listenerType=ZK_BROKER, nodeId=0] Enabling request processing. (kafka.network.SocketServer)
    [2023-07-29 09:26:08,614] INFO Awaiting socket connections on 0.0.0.0:9092. (kafka.network.DataPlaneAcceptor)
    [2023-07-29 09:26:08,662] INFO Kafka version: 3.5.0 (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser)
    [2023-07-29 09:26:08,662] INFO Kafka commitId: c97b88d5db4de28d (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser)
    [2023-07-29 09:26:08,662] INFO Kafka startTimeMs: 1690622768650 (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser)
    [2023-07-29 09:26:08,674] INFO [KafkaServer id=0] started (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
    [2023-07-29 09:26:38,617] INFO [Controller id=0, targetBrokerId=0] Disconnecting from node 0 due to socket connection setup timeout. The timeout value is 9708 ms. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
    [2023-07-29 09:26:38,625] INFO [Controller id=0, targetBrokerId=0] Client requested connection close from node 0 (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
    [2023-07-29 09:27:08,756] INFO [Controller id=0, targetBrokerId=0] Disconnecting from node 0 due to socket connection setup timeout. The timeout value is 11109 ms. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
    [2023-07-29 09:27:08,757] INFO [Controller id=0, targetBrokerId=0] Client requested connection close from node 0 (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
    [2023-07-29 09:27:38,873] INFO [Controller id=0, targetBrokerId=0] Disconnecting from node 0 due to socket connection setup timeout. The timeout value is 9853 ms. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
```

Comment: 1) Show your whole property file 2) Kafka no longer requires Zookeeper 3) Don't [repost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76771758/kafka-topic-creation-timed-out-waiting-for-a-node-assignment) the same issue; is there a specific reason not to try the suggestions I provided there?

Comment: Updated the logs in the question above. Earlier post was about click to deploy version which I could no make it work. Hence went with self hosted Kafka and working in one of the VM. However on another VM where I also installed the Kafka, running into this issue. I'm using Kafka 3.5. I must say you have been of great help in debugging. Thank you.

Comment: Added the logs which I missed  to add earlier.

Comment: considering cost aspects, team wants to use only self hosted Kafka than Confluent or other providers. Also not using JAAS instead PLAINTEXT, tried out all that I know or suggestion on web.

Comment: If you can run Kafka cheaper than Confluent, they'll pay you to prove it https://www.confluent.io/blog/understanding-and-optimizing-your-kafka-costs-part-4-savings-challenge/

Comment: Your issue might be related to the fact that 0.0.0.0 is not a routable IP. Use 127.0.0.1 if Zookeeper is on the same machine. But production ready Kafka clusters aren't running both on the same machine... Also, your VM will need at least 4G of RAM to run both as well as any other client applications (you didn't mention the GCP VM type). Or, mentioned before, just don't run Zookeeper and save some memory. Run Kafka in Kraft mode

Comment: Didn't get to try this out due to other open items, I will get back if I run into same issue again. Thank you so much for all the suggestions.